# Translate and billboard

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl

I've added a load of sprite vertices to a geometry object and am using a vertex shader to animate them individually.
Now I'd like to billboard them, after the translation, but my billboard matrix transform billboards the whole geometry object.
How can I get the billboard transform to act on individual sprites?

```
int spriteIndex = int(floor(position.x*particleSize));

            float displacementVal = displacement[spriteIndex].w;
            vec3 rotationDisplacement = displacement[spriteIndex].xyz;
            rotationDisplacement = normalize(rotationDisplacement);

            mat4 billboardMatrix = modelViewMatrix;
            int spherical = 1;

              billboardMatrix[0][0] = 1.0;
              billboardMatrix[0][1] = 0.0;
              billboardMatrix[0][2] = 0.0;

              if (spherical == 1)
              {

                billboardMatrix[1][0] = 0.0;
                billboardMatrix[1][1] = 1.0;
                billboardMatrix[1][2] = 0.0;
              }

              billboardMatrix[2][0] = 0.0;
              billboardMatrix[2][1] = 0.0;
              billboardMatrix[2][2] = 1.0;

            vec3 correctedPos = position-vec3((particleSize*float(floor(position.x/particleSize)))+(particleSize/2.),0,0);
            correctedPos = correctedPos + vec3(displacementVal-float(displacementWidth/2),0,0);

            vec4 mvPosition = billboardMatrix *  vec4(correctedPos,1);

            vec4 p = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

            gl_Position = p;
```

Comment: It's not clear where your sprite positions are coming from and what you mean by "sprite". Are you drawing a quad per sprite? Are you using `gl.POINTS`

Comment: I`m passing in a uniform array of vector rotations

Comment: The idea is to use these vectors to rotate the orbital paths of the quads
The quads are created  using threejs and merged into one geometry
Then Im using the quads x position to find an index to select a vector from the array